# Extract video from sony handycame with perfect quality

Tags: usb, video, encoding, tape, camcorder

I've got an old sony handycame that record into tapes. When i try to display the videos in my samsung tv using RCA cables, the video is full screen and with a really good quality.

I wanted to transfer the videos into my computer using usb communication. I've got the handycam's driver, installed, the handycam is recognized as well.

Using OpenCV library, have been able to collect the pictures but in a resolution of 320*240, resolution of the screen of my handycam.

When i try to resize the pictures, the quality get really bad. I would like to have videos of more than default resolution, with a good quality.

So, how come that the videos are displayed so well into the tv, but not in my computer ? and is there any way to solve this problem ?

CAMCORDER: DCR-TRV238E

TV: SAMSUNG PS43D450A2W

Comment: Yes, i have posted the reference of it in my post.

Comment: Those camcordrs are hi8 or digital8 if I recall. That is basically VHS or S-VHS ("standard def") which is probably going to translate to something between 320x240 and 640x480 and is probably interlaced. Probably the TV just handles the scaling and interlacing better. You should do some googling to see if 320x240 is downsampled, but any resizing should be done at capture time (getting it off the tape).

Comment: You can't add more information that doesn't exist. If the resolution is 320x240, which sounds right, you cant blow it up to 1920x1080 and expect it to look right. TVs are better equipped for making a low res image appear better. On a computer monitor it will look terrible. No matter what, it will always be 320x240.